# How to get AngularJS sanitizer to parse a block of html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I'm using sanitizer and ui-router together in a single module it's causing this error:

```
VM103 angular.js:9101 Parse Error: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" ng-app="sbAdmin2" class="ng-scope"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <meta name="description" content=""> <meta name="author" content="">  </div> </div><!-- /#wrapper --></body></html>
```

Here is my [code in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4nRK/101/).

The error occurs with this statement:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize','ui.router']);
```

I have found [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/lhbrIG5aBX4/4hYnzq2eGZwJ) which says to define these in separate modules.

Comment: `ui.router` should be module name

Comment: The sanitizer was unable to parse the following block of html:

Comment: hi pankaj i have html in which consist of whole html with js and css in html page how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The module name is `ui.router` not `ui-router`